# Special Relativity Textbooks Request

Tags: special-relativity, resource-recommendations, specific-reference

I have a copy of David Bohm's [Special Theory of Relativity](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0415404258) and also a copy of T.M. Helliwell's [Special Relativity](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1891389610). I was wondering if anyone has used these texts and if they're sufficient in providing an in depth inquiry into special relativity.

Comment: Related:  http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/95609/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Hi @MitchKnight, this question fits poorly on Phys.SE for various reasons e.g. it is _primarily opinion-based._ In particular, Phys.SE rarely provides book-reviews. I'm closing this as a _duplicate,_ not because it is an exact duplicate, but to guide you in the right direction.