# Tensor Calculus/Vector Calculus and so on in special relativity book recommandation

Tags: special-relativity, tensor-calculus, vectors, resource-recommendations, calculus

I want to learn calculus 1,2,3 vector calculus, analysis and so on in special relativity. But I never found a good and clear book/source on it. Can someone recommend an easy book or internet source on that? It should have:
Differentiation, integration, line/volume/surface integrals, vector analysis with all it's theorems and so on, the whole package with concrete examples. I think I could make up some examples myself, but I don't know if I'm doing this right because there are some thing that one has to keep in mind I think.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/95609/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/193/2451 and links therein.

Comment: For learning Calculus on-line, I can't imagine a better set of tutorials then those offered by the Khan Academy: https://www.khanacademy.org.

Comment: I wrote "in special relativity"

Comment: @JonnyPython   I am confused by your question.  Do you need to learn Calculus (or Vector Calculus) or do you already know Calculus (ditto) but need to know how it is applied to Special Relativity?  If you already know Calculus change your question to reflect that.  If you don't, I suggest you learn it first although learning the essence of Special Relativity does not need Calculus but maybe a good jolt of analytic geometry (for understanding coordinate systems).

Comment: Most E&M and Mechanics textbooks I've seen cover vector calculus & SR.

Comment: @K7PEH: I already know calculus and so on in cartesian space. But I want to focus on minkowski space. It's simple, I just want to do everything in minkowski space. At best with concret examples. For example how to do usual integrals, line integrals and so on. These are the tools to learn relativistic field theory, but I need some concret examples. I could make up examples myself, but there are a lot of constrains in SR, so I'm not sure that I would do it right.

Comment: @Kyle: Maybe relativistic electrodynamics?

Comment: @JonnyPython   If you want to understand classical physics using 4-vector notation (tensor calculus) there are a lot of good books.  My personal favorite though is "The Classical Theory of Fields" by Landau and Lifshitz.  Also, I recommend consider watching the Susskind lectures on Special Relativity that also covers a lot of classical field theory.  For Susskind lectures: http://theoreticalminimum.com/courses/special-relativity-and-electrodynamics/2012/spring

Comment: @K7PEH: Ah I looked at Laundau and it looks good. Thx

Comment: I think you are looking for Tensor calculus. With respect to that, I am suggesting an edit.