# Rigorous textbook about special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, resource-recommendations, education, mathematics

I want textbooks about special relativity that demonstrates  the relativistic phenomena  by deep details

Comment: there you go my friend : https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642372759

Comment: I just knew you were going to mention Gourgoulhon. I guess it is certainly detailed. See also G. L. Naber, The geometry of Minkowski spacetime, Springer, 2010.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/95609/2451

Comment: Karim, have a look at the books mentioned in [What are good books for special relativity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/325828/what-are-good-books-for-special-relativity).