# Seeking Advice to Dive into General and Special Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, resource-recommendations, education

I've got a second degree in engineering and a solid grip on the basics of physics. Now, I'm itching to take a deep dive into the worlds of general and special relativity.

I've explored some introductory stuff and feel ready to level up my understanding. Any recommendations for books, online courses, or other resources? I'm looking for something that fits well with an engineering background and isn't afraid to get a bit technical.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Books for general relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/363/)

Comment: See also https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/325828/2451